# VLOOKUP search by Email Address Not Working in LibreOffice or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice

My First Sheet

```
Customer_Email

a1b1y1@gmail.com
usharao_h@rediffmail.com
bhimdipti@gmail.com
ramyan249@gmail.com
kannans1690@gmail.com
puharaman@gmail.com
rajiishiva90cs@yahoo.com
vibeeshanans@hotmail.com
basker.p@gmail.com
puharaman@gmail.com
gopalvenki@yahoo.com
gopalvenki@yahoo.com
```

On 2nd Sheet

```
ID      Customer_Email

1058 18pe08@gmail.com
771 1991harishjayaraj@gmail.com
601 1995asrsanjay@gmail.com
619 2000.harikesh@gmail.com
459 678prabakaran@gmail.com
418 7411110424mm@gmail.com
590 98josh@gmail.com
557 a_rajendiran12@yahoo.co.in
226 a.p.praveen.30@gmail.com
702 a1b1y1@gmail.com
21  aartikolambkar@gmail.com
362 aaryahsingh77@gmail.com
1005    aaryan8587@gmail.com
167 aasshoka@gmail.com
966 abashwanth13@gmail.com
560 abbas15_99@yahoo.com
```

I need the corresponding ID from sheet2 to sheet1

The below one I used in sheet1's B2 Cell

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A$2:B$1000,1,0)
```

Returns N/A and the error shows `Did not find value 'a1b1y1@gmail.com' in VLOOKUP evaluation.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) syntax - the search for values takes place in the first column of the range. In your formula VLOOKUP tries to find the value `'a1b1y1@gmail.com'` in the column `Sheet2!A$2:A1000` and clearly can not find it there, because this text is in the range `Sheet2!B$2:B1000`

In **Google Sheets** you can use the following formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2,{Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A},2,0))` - here we swap the ranges for finding the key and the range for output directly in the formula

Comment: This one =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2,{Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A},2,0)) made it

Answer (score 0):

The lookup field must be the first column in your data table. Otherwise Vlookup will not work. That means your ID field must be after the Address.